# WPF MVVM Combobox Not Populating When Changing Selected Item On Another Control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, prism

It seems that I have this problem very often when working with comboboxes so my question will have 2 parts, First what am I doing wrong and why? I use Prism for many reasons, one of which is because I don't have to type out a `viewModelBase` (`INotifyPropertyChanged` class).

I like to have a list of records on the left side of the view to allow the end user to easily choose a record to view. In this case it is a `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.Row="3"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Grid.RowSpan="4"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSweepModel, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DatesList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Street"
                            Binding="{Binding Street.StreetName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date"
                            Binding="{Binding DateSwept}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name"
                            Binding="{Binding Employee.LastName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name"
                            Binding="{Binding Employee.FirstName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It is bound to an `ItemSource` called `DatesList` that is a `List<Model>`: *(please note that `SetProperty` is Prism's `INotifyPropertyChanged`)* and the `SelectedSweepModel`

```
    private List<SweeperModel> _datesList;
    public List<SweeperModel> DatesList
    {
        get { return _datesList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref(_datesList),value); }
    }

    private SweeperModel _selectedSweepModel;
    public SweeperModel SelectedSweepModel
    {
        get { return _selectedSweepModel; }
        set { SetProperty(ref (_selectedSweepModel), value); }
    }
```

SweeperModel:

```
public class SweeperModel
{
    public Streets Street { get; set; }
    public Streets IntersectingStreet1 { get; set; }
    public Streets IntersectionStreet2 { get; set; }
    public EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; }
    public string Quad { get; set; }
    public string Block { get; set; }
    public bool Am { get; set; }
    public bool Pm { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSwept { get; set; }
    public string UnitsRange { get; set; }
}
```

The comboBox is bound to a property in the `SweeperModel` called `Street`:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2"
          Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding StreetList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSweepModel.Street}"
          DisplayMemberPath="StreetName" />
```

The `Streets` class has 2 properties:

```
public class Streets
{
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public int StreetID { get; set; }
}

    private List<Streets> _streetList;
    public List<Streets> StreetList
    {
        get { return _streetList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref (_streetList), value); }
    }
```

When I select an `Item` nothing populates in the combobox. Now my question, what am I doing wrong?

Populating the Lists I run a stored procedure that returns a dataset with 3 tables.

and The 3 methods that populate the lists:

```
private void FillStreetList(DataTable dt)
{
    var myList = (from DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows
        select new Streets()
        {
            StreetID = dataRow.Field<int>("StreetID"),
            StreetName = dataRow.Field<string>("Streets")
        }).ToList();
    StreetList = myList;
}

private void FillEmployeeList(DataTable dt)
{
    var myList = (from DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows
                  select new EmployeeModel()
                  {
                      Id = dataRow.Field<int>("EmployeeID")
                      ,
                      FirstName = dataRow.Field<string>("FirstName")
                      ,
                      LastName = dataRow.Field<string>("LastName")
                      ,
                      Phone = dataRow.Field<string>("Phone")
                  }).ToList();

    EmployeeList = myList;
}

private void FillJobs(DataTable dt)
{
    var myList = (from DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows
                  orderby dataRow.Field<DateTime>("DateSwept"),
                          dataRow.Field<string>("LastName"),
                          dataRow.Field<string>("FirstName")
                    select new SweeperModel()
                    {
                        Am = dataRow.Field<bool>("TimeOfDayAm"),
                        Pm = dataRow.Field<bool>("TimeOfDayPm"),
                        Block = dataRow.Field<string>("Block"),
                        DateSwept = dataRow.Field<DateTime>("DateSwept"),
                        Employee = new EmployeeModel()
                        {
                            FirstName = dataRow.Field<string>("FirstName"),
                            LastName = dataRow.Field<string>("LastName"),
                            Id = dataRow.Field<int>("EmployeeID"),
                            Phone = dataRow.Field<string>("Phone")
                        },
                        IntersectingStreet1 = new Streets() {StreetName = dataRow.Field<string>("IntersectingStreet1Name"),StreetID = dataRow.Field<int>("IntersectingStreet1") },
                        UnitsRange = dataRow.Field<string>("UnitsRange"),
                        Quad = dataRow.Field<string>("Quad"),
                        Street = new Streets() { StreetName = dataRow.Field<string>("StreetName"), StreetID = dataRow.Field<int>("StreetID") }

                    }).ToList();
    DatesList = myList;

}
```

Comment: Where is property {Binding StreetList} come from?

Comment: I will edit my post to add

Comment: It would be helpful to see `DataContext` class and how lists are populated.

Comment: You should try [IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/binding_to_the_current_item_in_wpf.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different references to selected `Street` object. One reference comes from `StreetList` and another from `SelectedSweeperModel.Street` (SelectedItem). So combobox trying to find selected object by reference and fails. Binding to `StreetID` should solve the problem

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2"
      Grid.Row="1"
      ItemsSource="{Binding StreetList}"
      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSweepModel.Street.StreetID}"
      SelectedValuePath="StreetID"
      DisplayMemberPath="StreetName" />
```

Comment: Thank you Elder, How should I do that?